# Looking for a word to describe a period of time between an event is triggered and registered

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that would accurately describe the period of time between an event is triggered and registered. For an example, an alert is triggered when a threshold is reached, but the alert does not register in the system unless it stays beyond the threshold for a continuous 30 seconds.

Is there a word that defines that 30 seconds? I am thinking countdown but that feels like there are better choices out there.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like "duration".

Comment: I'd go with 'lapse'.

Comment: It is a 'delay'.

Comment: latency, or something related to filter. It seems like some sort of low-pass filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my work I would call it

> Processing time

or perhaps simply

> Delay

For example,

> There is a 30 second delay before the system registers an alert. If the signal drops below the threshold during this delay then an alert is not triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I like Tom's answer and am simply adding 'reaction time'
which, depending on the circumstances, may be appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking about a time frame that was intentionally built in to the system, as opposed to something dictated by the physics of the situation, I'd go with **delay threshold** when referring to the duration's lower bound. Delays are a common way to mitigate nuisance alarms. The reason you don't get an immediate engine shutdown for low oil pressure when you start a genset or compressor is there is a delay before the shutdown signal is sent. The delay is established to let the oil pressure build up and remove the signal.

Here's a link to a sensor with built-in delay.
[P28 Series Lube Oil Pressure Cutout Control with Time Delay](http://www.johnsoncontrols.com/-/media/jci/be/united-states/refrigeration/commercial-refrigeration/files/be_cat_penn_electromechanicallubeoildiffpressurecontrols.pdf)